# grep text before string - regex

Tags: regex, bash, grep

I have to extract few fields from below input html text using bash (only).

HTML input

```
<a href="/something/somemorething/page?id=1234425">SOMETEXT</a>
```

I have extract id value and SOMETEXT from above input.

I am hoping that grep using some regex should workout.
For `id_value` I am using following regex

```
"id=[0-9]*"
```

which is giving me correct results.

```
grep -o 'id=[0-9]*' index.html | head -n 5
```

But I am not sure what sort of regex I should use to grab text till next `</a>`.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regex you have in your OP (`"id=[0-9]*"`) looks like it worked in your case, but a better approach is to hone down on the anchor tags themselves.

Here is a regex to extract out the id value:

```
<a.*?id=(\d.*?)">
```

And here is a regex to extract out the contents inside the `<a>` tag:

```
<a.*?">(.*?)<\/a>
```

Comment: This works for me individually !! However it would be great if there is something combined? - I am very naive in regex so question can be wrong.

Comment: Try this: `grep -E 'REGEX1|REGEX2' index.html` ... are you looking for _both_ conditions to match, or just _one_ or the other?

Comment: Basically I want to extract both fields. And it should be available all the time - thats what I am assuming right now.

Answer (score 2):

```
(?<=>).*?(?=<)
```

You can use this with `grep -P`,since this uses lookarounds supported by perl.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/fM9lY3/21